# How to arrange a daily time log entry form in Microsoft Access 2007 with Weekdays & Dates in the column headings

Tags: database, windows, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

The objective is to create a weekly form, in Microsoft Access 2007, that allows employees to select their name from a list, the date of the first day of the week, and then create all daily time longs for the week in single form.  The form needs to have a week view like the form (an Excel mockup) shown here:

[image]

Once entered, the data is to be written to the Project Time Log table shown here:

[image]

When the employee selects the "Week Starting" value, the column headings in the able below need to update.  Is this possible?  What also has me stumped is how to enter project hours for the week in a single row that will result in creating up to 6 records in my database.  Finally, how does one set up validation on the "Week Starting" field so that the employee can only select Mondays?

I guess this is where I admit that I am just getting started with MS Access.  However, with some experience in database design and Excel I am finding everything but advanced form building to be fairly straightforward.

So, can someone point me in the right direction?  Do I need to use a Pivot Table to make this work?  What is a Modal Dialogue?  Could it be useful here?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way may be to create a table used solely for dataentry that can reside in the front-end for each employee.

```
DETable

EmployeeID
WeekStarting
ProjectID
Workcode
Mon
Tue
<...>
Sat
```

You can clear down the table and then append the relevant projectIDs and EmployeeID with a command button or suitable event.

The labels showing Mon, Tue etc can be updated to show the relevant date after  WeekStarting is selected.

A suitable set of queries, or a UNION query will allow you to append the data to the main table.

Comment: Please excuse the delayed response.  It took some learning before I could implement your suggestions.  Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: @Byron Fair play for taking the time and I hope it works out for you.